# Book Title; Freedom Group plots to bombard earth

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone identify a book I read as a kid in 1958/9? Probably a Badger Book, but I can't swear to it.

Richard Cartland is one of a number of criminals who volunteer to work in the Ferrinite mines on the Moon, in return for a year off the sentence for each month served. Unfortunately he may not live to benefit, as Ferrinite gives off lethal radiation. "Fourteen days of it and you're a corpse. A nasty messy corpse with running sores and rotting insides."

Cartland gets involved with the Freedom Group which seeks to overthrow the Earth Council. However, when he learns that their plans involve bombarding earth with atomic missiles, he turns against it and wins over enough of its members to defeat the plot. He is rewarded with a pardon and a place in the new spacefleet. The head of the Council tells him "The stars are yours".

Couple of other recollections. There is a horrible scene in which the Group's leader is blinded because he was wearing contact lenses when they blasted off - though we are told elsewhere that the acceleration was only 5g, which imho makes this a bit unlikely. Also I'm pretty sure that the first chapter was entitled "Ferrinite Is Death" and the last one "Death on Lunar" (not a typo, it really was spelt with an r).

Something else I've recalled. On the cover it had the words. "He lost his honour - and found it in the black deeps of space" or something extremely close to that. I think honour was spelt with a u, but again can't swear to it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[*Return to Space*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?301683) by [W. H. Fear](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?37316), John Spencer and Co/Badger Books, London, 1958.

Front cover blurb:

> HE LOST HIS HONOUR AND FOUND IT IN THE BLACK DEEPS OF SPACE

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome!